# Is there a way could detect what file be dragged in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanna write a VScode extension could detect what file be dragged into the TextEditor.

Does anyone know which vscode api I can use?

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.29, there is no API for this.

The feature request is being tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5240)